# Get LibreOffice to change the margins for all pages and not just the last page when select all pages is active?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, libreoffice, margins

I am using the template for a book from Createspace that is owned by Amazon. The template is a word document and there are various formatting styles in this template, and I want to change the margin size. I use cntrl-A to select all the text and then go to format page, and from there change the margins which effectively changes the formatting of the margins for the last page only. How can I make sure that every single page's margins are changed.

Template [links](https://www.createspace.com/en/community/docs/DOC-1323) on CreateSpace (using the top left entry in the table 5x8 formatted template)

Comment: There are many templates at that link. Which one are you having problems with?

Comment: @DavidPostill, (using the top left entry in the table 5x8 formatted template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I make sure that every single page's margins are changed?

The reason it wasn't working for you is that in the document every chapter has it's own (different) page style.

To fix this:

1. Press <kbd>f11</kbd> to display "Styles and Formatting"
2. Select "Page Styles"

   [image]
3. Delete all of the "Convert xx" pages styles (select the styles one by one and press <kbd>del</kbd>).

   - All pages will now have the "Default Style" page format.
4. Select the whole document <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>
5. Change the margins.
6. All pages will reflect the new margins (and retain the Page Layout "Mirrored" value).

Notes:

- **Every chapter has it's own (different) page style**.
- You can see this if you goto "Style and Formatting" (press <kbd>f11</kbd>) and look at "Page Styles" when you click through each page.
- The "Page Style" changes from "Default Style" > "Convert 1" > ... > "Convert 18".

Comment: @DavePosteill, thanks for the answer, I deleted the Convert page style from the popup menu after F11, but when doing the select all, and changing the page style, again only the last page was altered in margins

Comment: Hmm. It worked for me. Did you delete **all** of the "Convert" styles?

Comment: got it to work by deleting all of the First Convert styles below as well. :)

Comment: Great ....... ;)